# How can I clear a TDBImage field?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a TDBImage control. I want to clear/erase/empty through a TButton's click event. i.e., what's displayed on the screen, as opposed to what's in the underlying database which I could accomplish by setting to empty_blob().

It seems the actual image is stored in the Picture property (TPicture) but searching out TPicture has not helped either.

```
procedure TMyForm.clearPictureButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  photo.Picture.[WHAT GOES HERE????];
  // or
  // photo.Picture := [WHAT GOES HERE????];
end;
```

I logical candidates would be something called: `clear`, `erase`, `blank`, `empty`, etc.

`Free`, `Destroy` and `DisposeOf` clearly deal with releasing the memory for the control back to the OS.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to clear the TDBIMage, or the contents of the field that is connected to the TDBImage?

Comment: the part that's displayed on the screen. I can clear the DB at my leisure.

Answer (score 4):

Clear the `Picture` property:

```
photo.Picture := nil;
```

`TDBImage.Picture` is a property; assigning to it really calls the `Assign` method on the image control's internal `FPicture` field. Thus, the property doesn't actually *become* `nil`. Because of that disconnect, you might consider the above code slightly misleading to the naive reader. You can avoid that by typing a little mode:

```
photo.Picture.Assign(nil);
```

Comment: +1 because it works. With some more fighting and digging I think I've come up with a better option for me.